# Multiple XSD files with same entities defined

Tags: c#, xsd, svcutil.exe, xsd.exe

Thanks for any help,

We have two XSD files, both of them shares some same entities and some others different.  Note that the one with differences are called differently.

We want to generate C# code that can Serialize / Deserialize those entities, without ending up with two entities that share the same name and same content in two different namespaces.  An exemple of those are enums.

We did try with XSD.exe and SVCUTIL.exe, but could not found a proper way to do so.

Thanks again, gladly appreciated,

Patrick

Comment: Can you post a small example that demonstrates the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Trying using this

wsdl XMLSchema1.xsd XMLSchema2.xsd /language:c# /sharetypes